Transformer for Reinforcement Learning
I am developing a deep reinforcement learning agent which has a transition and value network. The agent interacts with the environment and from that experience trains the deep learning models like DDQN.
I am using a transformer to model a transition network. I am testing it on bsuite's DeepSea 3x3 grid environment but it is not able to converge. The next_state and reward predicted by this network is then passed to a value network (currently a simple deep learning NN) to learn values for planning.
For the transition (transformer network) currently I am only using 1 head, context_length is 1 (I am only passing current_state for now; when this works fine I intend to pass longer sequences), number of encoder blocks is 2 and forward_expansion is 4 with learning_rate 1e-2.
I collected 100 transitions and trained it over 100 epochs and only trained the transition network. The learning rate is 1e-2 with 16 neurons in each hidden layer.
These are some sample predictions:
Current state: 0    Action taken: tensor([0])   Pred next states: 3     pred_rewards: -0.016
Current state: 0    Action taken: tensor([1])   Pred next states: 4     pred_rewards: 0.017
Current state: 3    Action taken: tensor([0])   Pred next states: 6     pred_rewards: -0.0
Current state: 3    Action taken: tensor([1])   Pred next states: 7     pred_rewards: -0.002
Current state: 4    Action taken: tensor([0])   Pred next states: 6     pred_rewards: -0.002
Current state: 4    Action taken: tensor([1])   Pred next states: 8     pred_rewards: 0.716


I kept this transition network fixed because it is predicting the right next_state and tried to improve the value network.
The value network trained separately for 100 iterations with hidden_dims=16 and seems to be fine with MSE loss of 0.00292. These values are learnt for the states:
state: 0    value: 0.8944
state: 1    value: 0.4732
state: 2    value: 0.5983
state: 3    value: 0.8987
state: 4    value: 0.9916
state: 5    value: 0.3183
state: 6    value: -0.0185
state: 7    value: -0.0116
state: 8    value: 0.7127


This is the agent performance:

I am not sure what to improve for the agent to converge to a good performance.

Try swap out your own implementation with trl - this will give you a sense if the issue is in the model or the reward
